# I am trying to create a program that multiplies random numbers based on a maximum the user inputs

Tags: c++, random

Im not very good at this yet and I'm trying to learn how to get user declared variables to work within my equations.
For now I just want the computer to spit out a randomized multiplication based on a maximum number specified by the user.

When I try to run this the machine spits back these errors:

```
12:16: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> 32767'

14:61: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope

14:64: error: 'y' was not declared in this scope

15:16: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

20:9: error: declaration of 'int x' shadows a parameter

21:5: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'int
```

The eventual goal is that the computer will generate the problem within the difficulty parameter then remove one of the variables in the equation to quiz the user.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mult( int x, int y );

int main()
{
    cout <<"Please enter a number between 2 and 21, this will determine how difficult your problems are.";
    cin >> RAND_MAX;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "The product of your numbers is:" << mult ( x, y ) <<"\n";
    cin.get;
}

int mult (int x, int y)
{
    int x = rand()
    int y = rand()
    return  x * y;
}
```

Comment: What kind of problems are you having with your current code?

Comment: It wont run.  15:16: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
20:9: error: declaration of 'int x' shadows a parameter 21:5: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'int' Those are some of the errors the machine spits back at me.

Comment: You're getting the error "declaration of 'int x' shadows a parameter" because you're re-declaring x and y inside your function after they were already passed in as arguments.

Comment: The real question is why `cin >> 32767;` is ambiguous instead of having no matches.

Comment: So I can remove the first declaration of int x and y and leave it for later when I specify them to be randomly generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few errors here. I'll try and be kind.

1. You need semi-colons after both of your `rand()` calls.
2. `x` and `y` are not declared anywhere in `main()`. I don't know why you're passing them as parameters to `mult()`, but I assume there will be some related functionality down the line.
3. `RAND_MAX` is a constant,  so `cin >> RAND_MAX` makes no sense. Instead, see @Bill's answer.
4. You need parens after `cin.get`.

Here's a working example, hopefully this is what you want it to do:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mult( int x, int y, int randMax );

int main()
{
    int x = 0, 
        y = 0, 
        randMax;
    cout <<"Please enter a number between 2 and 21, this will determine how difficult your problems are.";
    cin >> randMax;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "The product of your numbers is:" << mult ( x, y, randMax ) <<"\n";
    cin.get();
}

int mult (int x, int y, int randMax)
{
    x = rand() % randMax;
    y = rand() % randMax;
    return  x * y;
}
```

Comment: Just pointing out that there's absolutely no point to having two non-reference parameters that you just assign to instead of creating local variables.

Comment: I was trying to change the OP's code as little as possible to get it working. Since his question was about compiler errors, and not design errors.

Comment: Yeah my biggest problem is that I understand the general idea of what im supposed to do but I really need to learn the syntax. In any case this definetly runs.

Comment: Im pretty sure there was also a function that tells the computer to show what it picks. List or something like that.

Comment: @chris You don't even need local variables. Just do `return (rand() % randMax) * (rand() % randMax);`

Comment: @PatLillis, You don't *need* them, but depending on what you do, they can make it easier to read.

Comment: @chris Very true. More a matter of style, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out problems such as trying to modify `RAND_MAX`, expecting that to change how `rand()` operates. I just want to show how to use the modern `<random>` library in place of `rand()`.

There are a number of reasons not to use `rand()`.

The reason which is most significant to your case is that it's not straightforward to use it to correctly get values in the range you want. The most common way people do it is something like `rand() % randMax + 1`, but for most values of `randMax` this will actually produce some numbers in the range [1,randMax] more often than other numbers. If it's important to get evenly distributed numbers then you need something more like:

```
int v;
do {
  v = rand();
} while (v >= RAND_MAX / randMax * randMax);
v = v % randMax + 1;
```

which isn't so simple. `<random>` provides many pre-made distributions so you often don't have to write your own like this.

Other reasons not to use `rand()` are that it's not thread safe or easy to use in a multithreaded program, and that usually it's not very random. `<random>` can be used to fix these problems as well.

Here's a version of your program using `<random>`.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

// global random number engine and distribution to use in place of rand()
std::default_random_engine engine;
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution;

int mult()
{
    int x = distribution(engine);
    int y = distribution(engine);
    return  x * y;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a number between 2 and 21, this will determine how difficult your problems are.";

    int max;
    std::cin >> max;

    // set the global distribution based on max
    distribution.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<>(1,max).param());

    std::cout << "The product of your numbers is:" << mult() << "\n";
}
```